# Lottery Game using Math.random() in java

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

We are assigned to develop a program  to play lottery.The program will randomly generates lottery of a two-digit numbers, and prompts the user to input a two-digit numbers. And if the numbers is only a single digit(0-9) the numbers must be treated as a two-digit number (00 - 09). Below are the conditions:

1. If the user input matches the lottery numbers in exact order, the reward is Php 100,000.
2. If all numbers in the user input matches all the lottery numbers, the reward is Php 30,000.
3. If only one number in the user input matches a lottery number, the reward is Php 10,000.

This is my code so far...I actually have a problem on the 2nd condition (reward is Php30,000) whenever I matched only 1 number it says that "You matched all the lottery numbers. You won Php30,000."

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lottery = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lottery1, lottery2, lottery3;
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t~Welcome to THE LOTTERY~");
    System.out.println("Enter your first two-digit lucky number!");
    int guess1 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second two-digit lucky number!");
    int guess2 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your last two-digit lucky number!");
    int guess3 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nThe winning numbers are: ");
    System.out.printf("%02d", lottery1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10));
    System.out.printf("\n" + "%02d", lottery2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10));
    System.out.printf("\n" + "%02d", lottery3 = (int)(Math.random() * 10));
    if(guess1 == lottery1 && guess2 == lottery2 && guess3 == lottery3 ){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched all the lottery numbers in order.");
        System.out.println("You won Php100,000!");
    }else if(guess1 == lottery1 || lottery1 == guess1 && guess1 == lottery2 || lottery2 == guess1 && guess1 == lottery3 || lottery3 == guess1
            && guess2 == lottery1 || lottery1 == guess2 && guess2 == lottery2 || lottery2 == guess2 && guess2 == lottery3 || lottery3 == guess1
            && guess3 == lottery1 || lottery1 == guess3 && guess3 == lottery2 || lottery2 == guess3 && guess3 == lottery3 || lottery3 == guess3){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched all the lottery numbers.");
        System.out.println("You won Php30,000!");
    }else if(guess1 == lottery1 || guess1 == lottery2 || guess1 == lottery3
            || guess2 == lottery1 || guess2 == lottery2 || guess2 == lottery3
            || guess3 == lottery1 || guess3 == lottery2 || guess3 == lottery3){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched a lottery number.");
        System.out.println("You won Php10,000!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("\n\nSorry, your lucky numbers didn't matched any of the lottery numbers!");
    }
}`
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: It seems like this is a question from class, and one of the things that you should have learned is to make variable names meaningful. Would you mind giving better names so that they're more readable to us?

Comment: `l == a || a == l && l == b || b == l ` that is a pointless set of tests. If a is not equal to b you don't need to test if b is equal to a (it isn't). You missed at least one condition (two numbers match out of three); and you can handle your scenarios beyond the first with a counter.

Comment: Also, operator precedence  will take effect and it will end up being something like `1 == a || (a == 1 && 1 == b) || (b == l && l == c) ...` because the `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: burrito77 I did make that code..our teacher just told us what are the conditions

Comment: @AngelLyn actually, give me like 5 mins. I forgot that order doesn't matter

Comment: @AngelLyn quick clarification: is the second statement supposed to evaluate whether the person guessed at least 2 of the
 numbers, or is it supposed to evaluate if the person guessed all three correctly, but just didn't get them in
 the correct order?

Comment: the person guessed all the three numbers correctly but did not guessed them in order

Comment: @AngelLyn would you be fine if I simply uploaded the corrected code or would you like an explanation as well?

Comment: I'm fine with the corrected code but if the code is difficult to understand, then I will need the explanation..:)

Comment: @AngelLyn Note that having such long conversations like seen here and at the answer indicates that your question had too less information to form an answer that fulfills all your requirements. Therefore, next time you should take more time to think about your requirements and then include them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lottery = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lottery1, lottery2, lottery3;
    int guess1, guess2, guess3;
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t~Welcome to THE LOTTERY~");
    System.out.println("Enter your first two-digit lucky number!");
    guess1 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second two-digit lucky number!");
    guess2 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your last two-digit lucky number!");
    guess3 = lottery.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The winning numbers are: ");
    System.out.printf("%02d", lottery1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100));
    System.out.printf("\n" + "%02d", lottery2 = (int)(Math.random() * 100));
    System.out.printf("\n" + "%02d", lottery3 = (int)(Math.random() * 100));
    if(guess1 == lottery1 && guess2 == lottery2 && guess3 == lottery3){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched all the lottery numbers in order.\nYou won Php100, 000!");
    }
    else if(((guess1 == lottery1) || (guess1 == lottery2) || (guess1 == lottery3))
            && ((guess2 == lottery1) || (guess2 == lottery2) || (guess2 == lottery3))
            && ((guess3 == lottery1) || (guess3 == lottery2) || (guess3 == lottery3))){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched all the lottery numbers.\nYou won Php30, 000!");
    }
    else if(guess1 == lottery1 || guess1 == lottery2 || guess1 == lottery3
        || guess2 == lottery1 || guess2 == lottery2 || guess2 == lottery3
        || guess3 == lottery1 || guess3 == lottery2 || guess3 == lottery3){
        System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! You matched a lottery number.\nYou won Php10, 000!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("\n\nSorry, your lucky numbers didn't matched any of the lottery numbers!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain your changes? Also, highlight them.

Comment: @Zabuza see our conversation underneath the question above.

Comment: @AngelLyn good catch. I just did that so that I could test them instead of relying on luck.

Comment: @AngelLyn You do understand how the code works though, right?

Comment: @AngelLyn and why yours doesn't?

Comment: I understand mine. It just happen that there are some mistakes in my code

Comment: @AngelLyn, yeah, do you understand the mistakes?

Comment: @burrito77 There are still some mistakes in the 2nd condition..:)

Comment: @AngelLyn could you add the test casea which show the mistakes?

Comment: @AngelLyn oh, I see, I made it so it checks if the user got 2 or more correct. let me fix that